# emulate screen size with urllib2 and python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib2, scrape

I am trying to scrape a webpage, but it uses a javascript that detects screen height and dont let me access the page because my screen size is less than 11pixels. Is there a way to emulate browser size with urllib2?

```
!function(){try{!function(){var e=navigator.userAgent,r=e.indexOf("Android")>-1&&e.indexOf("Mozilla/5.0")>-1&&e.indexOf("AppleWebKit")>-1,n=new RegExp(/AppleWebKit\/([\d.]+)/),a=n.exec(e),d=null===a?null:parseFloat(n.exec(e)[1]);return r&&null!==d&&d<537}()?window.isIeLowerThan11?document.getElementById("old-browser-root").innerHTML='<div class="alert alert--danger alert--small-margin hidden-print" id="oldIeBrowser">I nuläget stöds inte din webbläsare av ATG.se. Här kan du ladda ned en ny webbläsare: <a href="https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/" target="_blank">Ladda ner Google Chrome</a></div>':/Edge\//.test(navigator.userAgent)&&(window.fetch=void 0):document.getElementById("old-browser-root").innerHTML='<div class="alert alert--danger alert--small-margin hidden-print" id="oldAndroidBrowser">Vi rekommenderar att du använder Google Chrome som webbläsare. Det är inte säkert att ATG.se fungerar optimalt i din nuvarande webbläsare.<a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android.chrome">Ladda ner Google Chrome</a></div>'}catch(e){}}()
```

Comment: Please include the JS code that detects the dimensions.

Comment: How is JS code being executed if you just getting the html response? The javascript in the webpage shouldn't have any effect unless you are actually running the JS code you got from a your GET request.